# Is BehaviorSubject the same as shareReplay(1)?

Tags: rxjs

In these two examples, does `subject$` behave in exactly the same way?

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

let source: Observable<number>;
let subject$: Observable<number>;

subject$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

source.subscribe(x => {
  subject$.next(x);
});
```

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

let source: Observable<number>;
let subject$: Observable<number>;

subject$ = source.pipe(
  startWith(0),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Comment: Are you asking whether BehaviorSubject replays? [It does.](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject)

Comment: I mean, is there any difference in how `BehaviorSubject` behaves compared to `shareReplay`? If I were to refactor code from one to the other would it be possible to cause a different behavior? I think the time of the subscription could be different since in the 2nd example `source` will only be subscribed to once `subject$` is subscribed to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic difference is that the 0 value may be re-emitted to the upstream when all subscribers unsubscribe and similar subtleties when no subscribers are active.

e.g.:

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';

const source = new Subject<number>();
const subject$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);
source.subscribe((x) => {
  subject$.next(x);
});

source.next(1);
source.next(2);

let subscription = subject$.subscribe(console.log);

source.next(3);
source.next(4);

subscription.unsubscribe();

source.next(5);
source.next(6);

subscription = subject$.subscribe(console.log);

source.next(7);
source.next(8);

// Prints: 2 3 4 6 7 8
```

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = new Subject<number>();
const subject$ = source.pipe(startWith(0), shareReplay(1));

source.next(1);
source.next(2);

let subscription = subject$.subscribe(console.log);

source.next(3);
source.next(4);

subscription.unsubscribe();

source.next(5);
source.next(6);

subscription = subject$.subscribe(console.log);

source.next(7);
source.next(8);

// Prints 0 3 4 6 7 8
```

Comment: If the `source` was a `BehaviorSubject` in your 2nd example, and you remove `startWith(0)`, the two examples will behave exactly the same. That's useful if you don't want to expose the BehaviorSubject (e.g. if you want satisfy `eslint(rxjs/no-exposed-subjects)`).

Answer (score 3):

They replay behavior is the same but number of emission replay can be configured with shareReplay but not with BehaviorSubject. The main difference is shareReplay is an operator which can be add into pipe and convert any source stream to replay value and it doesn't replay any value until first emission happen.
BehaviorSubject is a class which only replay one value and need to be instantiated with a default value and thus when subscribe it always return one cached value.